# 2 or more cloth simulations on one object

Tags: cloth-simulation

I tried researching but seems no one else asked this question before me- correct me if I am wrong.
I have a plate of noodles modelled and simulated in Blender, and I need to find a way to apply new cloth simulations to my noodles model (which is multiple thin cylinders in one mesh)
Right now the only way I found around this is that I make a copy of my blend file and at the end of simulation #1 make a new one with the needed changes. Very time-consuming.
If anyone has a solution to this would appreciate greatly!

Comment: Can you explain further, what is whole purpose of this? Why do you need to continue with separate simulation. What is the purpose to duplicate file?

Comment: @vklidu sorry for taking a long time to reply and thank you for your question, the purpose is to keyframe the internal springs for my cloth object. The internal springs are not keyframe-able, and I needed it to decrease with time. The only way to do that I found was to duplicate the cloth sim object and enter a lesser internal springs value starting at the end of the first simulation. That was basically the question - is there an easier way to this ? And in advance sorry, I am not an expert in Blender

Comment: More than one sim is not possible (if you try to ad another Cloth sim modifier, bottom row is warning you). What exactly do you want to decrease? Some values like Tension, Compression can be animated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That is true, about the tension, compression, yes. What i needed animated was the internal springs of the cloth object as i am doing an animation of noodles falling down into a bowl - the internal springs add that bounciness & tension to the object when it falls. I needed it to start decreasing when the noodles settle into the bowl collision object - and that was the reason I "split" the simulation to start the second one off from where the first sim left off, but with the lesser internal springs value, so that the noodles settle into the bowl looking natural-like.

Comment: Sorry it seems to me we are walking in a circle ... I tried to summarised into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

More than one sim is not possible
(if you try to add another Cloth sim modifier, bottom row is warning you).

---

The **Internal Springs** is bunch of parameters. If you say "I can't animate Internal Springs", what parametr do you mean exactly?
Internal Springs (whole panel) has only check box, that can't be lowered, it can be only switched on/off.

If you want to affect sim by less IS just animate **Tension / Compression** from something to zero value. Here in 150 frame animation goes at frame 80 from 30 to 0 at frame 120 ... so IS fully affects object up to frame 80 and at frame 120 has no effect at object.

[image]

The only two values can't be animated and that is for a reason - sim would be explosive if you would change number of springs in a process of sim.

[image]